# Session not created error when running e2e tests

Tags: protractor

I am currently getting the below error when running my e2e tests using ng e2e

```
   SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
```

Below is the list of versions I have installed currently:

```
 chromedriver: 74.0.3729.6 (latest)
 geckodriver: 0.24.0 (latest)
 selenium: 3.141.59 (latest)
 protractor: 5.4.1
```

I tried deleting the node_modules folder and do a npm install again. Did not work though.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Some extra info on this: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/379

Answer (score 0):

Your ChromeDriver asks for Google Chrome version 75 installed on your computer. But Google Chrome version 75 isnt available yet, as i know. I have same issue now.
  I have had same problem with Google Chrome version 74. And untill they released 74 version i wasnt able to solve this, but i know it helped someone to use Google Chrome not of latest version by updating selenide(in this case) to latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing chromedriver v. 2.46 (Chrome 71-73) LOCALLY AND GLOBALLY

for the global installation run

`webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.46`

for local installation run something like

`node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.46`

List of driver versions is here http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Let me know if you run into issues